# Function of Javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry if this question is too trivial. Since I'm a beginner, it is difficult for me to understand some explanation. What is the meaning of the following statement?

"To keep the browser from executing a script when the page loads, you can put your script into a function."

Comment: Where did you read that? I have doubts of the source...

Comment: @Isaac Google gives me this page: http://www.zeali.net/mirrors/w3cshool/js/js_functions.asp.html

Comment: That source actually contains the explanation: _“If the line: `alert("Hello world!!")` in the example above had not been put within a function, it would have been executed as soon as the line was loaded. Now, the script is not executed before the user hits the button.”_. Did you read the full page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the author meant that if you do this:

```
<script>
  alert('Hello');
</script>
```

The script will run when the page load. But you can wrap that in a function:

```
<script>
  function hello() {
    alert('Hello');
  }
</script>
```

So instead of popping "Hello" the script will register the function that can be called later from another place/script to display "Hello" on the screen.

Comment: Thanks! This answer really help.

Answer (score 1):

The script wont be executed until the function is called, otherwise the script will automatically execute when it the page loads. :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following script

```js
alert("hey");
```

Browser pauses html rendering and tries to download the javascript and execute it.

This code simply involves an alert message,there could be dom search ,so to avoid this you consider doing as follows

```js
Greet();
function Greet(){
alert("hello");  
}
```

In this, until you call greet method ,script wont execute .So html rendering does not stop.

Consider if your code has dom search, even adding functions would not help
Here, you should consider using window.onload or $(document).ready

```js
window.onload=function(){
 var div= document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  div[0].innerHTML="Hello";
}
```

```html
<div>
  </div>
```